# My Y axis won't appear in my graph that I scripted?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

On here again with another tedious problem that I can't seem to solve, this bit of programming isn't showing the Y-axis title which I've called "Voltage Input". It shows my X-axis title and the main title as well but not the Y-axis, can anyone see why?

```
function lineGraph() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getRange("B15:W16");
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
    .asScatterChart().setTitle("Voltage Output")
    .setYAxisTitle("Voltage Input")
    .setXAxisTitle("Frequency")
    .addRange(row)
    .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
    .setOption('trendlines.0.labelInLegend', 'Trend line for V')
    .setOption('trendlines.0.visibleInLegend', true)
    .setOption('trendlines.0.showR2', true)
    .setOption('trendlines.0.type', 'linear')
    .setPosition(18,2,0,13)
    .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
    .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
  
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue for my proposed answer. So, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. And, that is also useful for me to study. Also I think that your this question is useful for other users who have the same issue. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asScatterChart().setTitle("Voltage Output")
  .setYAxisTitle("Voltage Input")
  .setXAxisTitle("Frequency")
  .addRange(row)
  .setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')
  .setOption('trendlines.0.labelInLegend', 'Trend line for V')
  .setOption('trendlines.0.visibleInLegend', true)
  .setOption('trendlines.0.showR2', true)
  .setOption('trendlines.0.type', 'linear')
  .setPosition(18,2,0,13)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .build();
```

#### To:

```
var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .asScatterChart().setTitle("Voltage Output")
  .setXAxisTitle("Frequency")
  .addRange(row)
  .setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Voltage Input", textStyle: {color: "#000000"}}})
  .setOption('trendlines.0.labelInLegend', 'Trend line for V')
  .setOption('trendlines.0.visibleInLegend', true)
  .setOption('trendlines.0.showR2', true)
  .setOption('trendlines.0.type', 'linear')
  .setPosition(18,2,0,13)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .build();
```

- `setYAxisTitle("Voltage Input")` and `setOption('vAxes.0.textStyle.color', '#000000')` are modified to `setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Voltage Input", textStyle: {color: "#000000"}}})`.
- The color of `#000000` is the black. But if you want to change the color except for it, in the case of `textStyle: {color: "#000000"}`, the color of each number of the vertical axis is changed. If you want to change the font color of title of the vertical axis, for example, please modify as follows.

  ```
    .setOption("vAxes", {0: {title: "Voltage Input", titleTextStyle: {color: "red"}}})
  ```

#### References:

- [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)
- [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)